# '&' symbol create </p> tag in html email

Tags: html, .net-core

I have an email template that has a section like this

```
<p>Customer's Name: $CustomerName</p>
```

The problem is whenever `$CustomerName` token is replaced with a text that has '&' symbol it will create another `</p>` tag in the HTML body when it's opened in the browser.

```
<p>Customer's Name: John & Doe </p></p>
```

**Thing(s) I've done**

1. Check generated email body: I've checked the logs, the email body looks good to me. It doesn't have additional `</p>` tag
2. Try a different browser: I tried on Edge and Chrome the result is the same
3. Try a different email provider: I tried on Gmail and One Drive the result is the same

Any idea what might cause this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you sure the customer's name doesn;t include ``</p>`` ?

Comment: There is no reason why `&` should create new `p`... Try to use `htmlspecialchars` (you should do it automatically and always) but I mean the problem is elsewhere. *htmlspecialchars function is in PHP, now I see `.net-core` tag, but the meaning of this comment is obvious. Escaping.

Comment: it could be due to html entities eg.  &nbsp;

Comment: Can you replace & with &amp;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the feedback I re-investigated the flow of code.

I found the root cause of the issue

- HTML template that I used was already encoded
- The token is not encoded

These condition make this:

**Email before decode**

```
&lt;p style=" color: #4a4a4a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; display: block; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 0; outline: none !important; " &gt; Organisation Name: * **ppyzh & 2 &lt;/p&gt;
```

**Email after decode**

```
 <p style=" color: #4a4a4a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; display: block; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 0; outline: none !important; " > Organisation Name: * **ppyzh & 2 &lt;/p>
```

Reference: [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode fails to decode &#39](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27582136/httputility-htmldecode-fails-to-decode-39)

---

Thanks for everyone that gave the feedback